# "need help using" vs "need help to use"

Tags: differences, gerund-vs-infinitive

> Let me know if you need any help **using** the computer.

I don't understand why 'use' ends with -ing. Shouldn't we use 'to' after the verb-'need'?

If I can say “I need **to use** the computer now”, why is the gerund used in the sentence above?

Comment: Note that the object of *need* is the noun phrase "any help using the computer". Whether *help* is followed by *using* or *to use* is not dependent on the verb *need*.

Answer (score 2):

"using the computer" is the task and refers to the "present time" (i.e., the period in which the computer is used).  There is an implied "with": Let me know if you need any help with [using the computer].  The help sought is in accomplishing tasks with the computer, while it is in use.

"to use the computer" refers to a future event.  "Let me know if you need any help to use the computer" refers to assistance in overcoming an obstacle to begin using it, like how to turn it on.